# How to catch the iPhone VoiceOver event?

Tags: iphone, ios, voiceover

Is there any way to catch the [VoiceOver - ON/OFF] event in my application?

I need to make my menu behave differently in two cases, using voiceover and normal way.

Answer (score 2):

```
UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning()
```

This returns a `BOOL` `YES` if it is running. This is iOS 4 and later.

Answer (score 2):

If you need it as a notification, `UIAccessibilityVoiceOverStatusChanged` (also 4.0+).

Answer (score 0):

In your app delegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method, subscribe to the VoiceOver status change like this:

```
//  subscribing to VoiceOver change notification:
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(didChangeVoiceOverSetting:)
     name:UIAccessibilityVoiceOverStatusChanged
     object:nil];
```

And then do whatever you need to do. In my app I have tons of accessibility code that is set up in the viewDidLoad methods of my code, so the easiest thing is to just crash the app on a VoiceOver change and allow everything to be re-initialized:

```
- (void)didChangeVoiceOverSetting:(NSNotification *)dictionary {
    // intentionally crashing the app if VoiceOver is changed
    assert(false);
}
```